# Add button to add additional input fields and assign them new id/name HTML/PHP/JS

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to figure out how to add a button that will add additional html input fields so that I don't have to predetermine the maximum amount that will be needed like I have here:
  [Screenshot of page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8Iy8.png)

I'd like to be able to add a simple 'Add Author' button or 'Add University' in case an author has 2 universities. Right now I am having to enter author name 2x to input 2 different universities. It would also need to rename input id each time button is clicked.... Help is greatly appreciated!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Input Form - Research Ranker</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/../img/favicon.ico">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
   <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#article_name" ).autocomplete({
      source: 'articlesearch.php'
    });
    $( "#author1_name" ).autocomplete({
      source: 'authorsearch.php'
    });
    $( "#author2_name" ).autocomplete({
      source: 'authorsearch.php'
    });
    $( "#author3_name" ).autocomplete({
      source: 'authorsearch.php'
    });
    $( "#author4_name" ).autocomplete({
      source: 'authorsearch.php'
    });
    $( "#author5_name" ).autocomplete({
      source: 'authorsearch.php'
    });
    $( "#author6_name" ).autocomplete({
      source: 'authorsearch.php'
    });
    $( "#author1_university" ).autocomplete({
      source: 'universitysearch.php'
    });
    $( "#author2_university" ).autocomplete({
      source: 'universitysearch.php'
    });
    $( "#author3_university" ).autocomplete({
      source: 'universitysearch.php'
    });
    $( "#author4_university" ).autocomplete({
      source: 'universitysearch.php'
    });
    $( "#author5_university" ).autocomplete({
      source: 'universitysearch.php'
    });
    $( "#author6_university" ).autocomplete({
      source: 'universitysearch.php'
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>



<?PHP
 
if(!isset($_POST['submit'])){
    print '
 <div class="container-fluid ui-widget">


 <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="articleinput2.php" onsubmit="return confirm("Is all of your data correct?");">
 <fieldset>

 <!-- Article Input -->
 <legend>Article Input</legend>

 <!-- Journal Radio Buttons (value is journal ISSN)-->
 <div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="journal_radio">Journal</label>
   <div class="col-md-4">
   <div class="radio">
  <label for="journal_radio-0">
    <input type="radio" name="journal_radio" id="journal_radio-0" value="2162-9730" checked="checked">
    MIS Quarterly
  </label>
   </div>
   <div class="radio">
  <label for="journal_radio-1">
    <input type="radio" name="journal_radio" id="journal_radio-1" value="1047-7047">
    Information Systems Research
  </label>
   </div>
   <div class="radio">
  <label for="journal_radio-2">
    <input type="radio" name="journal_radio" id="journal_radio-2" value="0742-1222">
    Journal of Management Information Systems
  </label>
   </div>
   <div class="radio">
  <label for="journal_radio-3">
    <input type="radio" name="journal_radio" id="journal_radio-3" value="1536-9323">
    Journal of the Association for Information Systems
  </label>
   </div>
   <div class="radio">
  <label for="journal_radio-4">
    <input type="radio" name="journal_radio" id="journal_radio-4" value="1476-9344">
    European Journal of Information Systems
  </label>
   </div>
   <div class="radio">
  <label for="journal_radio-5">
    <input type="radio" name="journal_radio" id="journal_radio-5" value="1365-2575">
    Information Systems Journal
  </label>
   </div>
   <div class="radio">
  <label for="journal_radio-6">
    <input type="radio" name="journal_radio" id="journal_radio-6" value="0963-8687">
    Journal of Strategic Information Systems
  </label>
   </div>
   <div class="radio">
  <label for="journal_radio-7">
    <input type="radio" name="journal_radio" id="journal_radio-7" value="0268-3962">
    Journal of Information Technology
  </label>
   </div>
   <div class="radio">
  <label for="journal_radio-8">
    <input type="radio" name="journal_radio" id="journal_radio-8" value="0167-9236">
    Decision Support Systems
  </label>
   </div>
   <div class="radio">
  <label for="journal_radio-9">
    <input type="radio" name="journal_radio" id="journal_radio-9" value="0378-7206">
    Information and Management
  </label>
   </div>
   </div>
 </div>

 <!-- Article Name Input-->
 <div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="article_name">Article Name:</label>  
   <div class="col-md-5">
   <input id="article_name" name="article_name" type="text" placeholder="Article Name" class="form-control input-md" required="" maxlength = "60">
  
   </div>
 </div>

 <!-- Author 1-->
 <div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="author1_name">Author 1:</label>  
   <div class="col-md-4">
   <input id="author1_name" name="author1_name" type="text" placeholder="Author Name" class="form-control input-md" required="" maxlength="40">
  
   </div>
 </div>

 <!-- Author 1 University -->
 <div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="author1_university">University:</label>  
   <div class="col-md-4">
   <input id="author1_university" name="author1_university" type="text" placeholder="Author University" class="form-control input-md" required="" maxlength="55">
  
   </div>
 </div>

 <!-- Author 2-->
 <div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="author2_name">Author 2:</label>  
   <div class="col-md-4">
   <input id="author2_name" name="author2_name" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" maxlength="40">
  
   </div>
 </div>

 <!-- Author 2 University-->
 <div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="author2_university">University:</label>  
   <div class="col-md-4">
   <input id="author2_university" name="author2_university" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" maxlength="55">
  
   </div>
 </div>

 <!-- Author 3-->
 <div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="author3_name">Author 3:</label>  
   <div class="col-md-4">
   <input id="author3_name" name="author3_name" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" maxlength="40">
  
   </div>
 </div>

 <!-- Author 3 University-->
 <div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="author3_university">University:</label>  
   <div class="col-md-4">
   <input id="author3_university" name="author3_university" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" maxlength="55">
  
   </div>
 </div>

 <!-- Author 4-->
 <div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="author4_name">Author 4: </label>  
   <div class="col-md-4">
   <input id="author4_name" name="author4_name" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" maxlength="40">
  
   </div>
 </div>

 <!-- Author 4 University-->
 <div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="author4_university">University:</label>  
   <div class="col-md-4">
   <input id="author4_university" name="author4_university" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" maxlength="55">
  
   </div>
 </div>

 <!-- Author 5-->
 <div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="author5_name">Author 5:</label>  
   <div class="col-md-4">
   <input id="author5_name" name="author5_name" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" maxlength="40">
  
   </div>
 </div>

 <!-- Author 5 University-->
 <div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="author5_university">University:</label>  
   <div class="col-md-4">
   <input id="author5_university" name="author5_university" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" maxlength="55">
  
   </div>
 </div>

 <!-- Author 6-->
 <div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="author6_name">Author 6:</label>  
   <div class="col-md-4">
   <input id="author6_name" name="author6_name" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" maxlength="40">
  
   </div>
 </div>

 <!-- Author 6 University-->
 <div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="author6_university">University:</label>  
   <div class="col-md-4">
   <input id="author6_university" name="author6_university" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" maxlength="55">
  
   </div>
 </div>

 <!-- Select Year Published -->
 <div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="year">Year Published</label>
   <div class="col-md-4">
  <select id="year" name="year" class="form-control">
    <option value="2010">2010</option>
    <option value="2011">2011</option>
    <option value="2012">2012</option>
    <option value="2013">2013</option>
    <option value="2014">2014</option>
    <option value="2015">2015</option>
  </select>
   </div>
 </div>

 <!-- Is Security Checkbox -->
 <div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="is_security"></label>
   <div class="col-md-4">
  <label class="checkbox-inline" for="is_security">
    <input type="checkbox" name="is_security" id="is_security" value="1">
    Security Related
  </label>
   </div>
 </div>

 <!-- Submit Form Button -->
 <div class="form-group">
   <div class="col-md-4 control-label">
  <button id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
   </div>
 </div>

 </fieldset>
 </form>


 </div>';
 
 } else {
  
  $dbHost = "localhost";
  $dbUsername = "admin";
  $dbPassword = "";
  $dbName = "webdb";

  // Create connection
  $db = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);
  // Check connection
  if ($db->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $db->connect_error);
  } else {
  // Post PHP variables
  $journal = $_POST['journal_radio'];
  $article_name = $_POST['article_name'];
  $author1 = $_POST['author1_name'];
  $author1uni = $_POST['author1_university'];
  $author2 = $_POST['author2_name'];
  $author2uni = $_POST['author2_university'];
  $author3 = $_POST['author3_name'];
  $author3uni = $_POST['author3_university'];
  $author4 = $_POST['author4_name'];
  $author4uni = $_POST['author4_university'];
  $author5 = $_POST['author5_name'];
  $author5uni = $_POST['author5_university'];
  $author6 = $_POST['author6_name'];
  $author6uni = $_POST['author6_university'];
  $year = $_POST['year'];
  $security = $_POST['is_security'];
  function authorinfoinsert($author, $number, $authoruni, $articleid, $article, $db){
    //check if Author already exists
    $authorquery = $db->query("SELECT Author_Name FROM Authors WHERE Author_Name = '$author'");
    if($authorquery->num_rows != 0) {
       echo '<a href=""> New Input </a><br />';
       echo 'Author ' . $number . ' - ' . $author . ' - already present<br />';
   
    } else {
     //insert author if doesnt exist
     $authorinsert = "INSERT INTO Authors (Author_Name) VALUES ('$author')";
    
     if ($db->query($authorinsert) === TRUE) {
     echo 'Author ' . $number . ' - ' . $author . ' - created successfully.<br />';
     } else {
     echo 'Error: ' . $authorinsert . '<br />' . $db->error . '<br />';
     }
      }
      
    // store Author Author_ID value
    
    
    $result = $db->query("SELECT Author_ID FROM Authors WHERE Author_Name = '$author'");
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $authorid = $row['Author_ID'];
    
    
    //check if Author University exists
    $authoruniquery = $db->query("SELECT University_Name FROM University WHERE University_Name = '$authoruni'");
    
    if($authoruniquery->num_rows != 0) {
       echo '<a href=""> New Input </a><br />';
       echo 'Author ' . $number . ' University already present <br />';
   
    } else {
     //insert university if doesnt exist
     $uniinsert = "INSERT INTO University (University_Name) VALUES ('$authoruni')";
    
     if ($db->query($uniinsert) === TRUE) {
     echo 'Author ' . $number . ' University - ' . $authoruni . ' - created successfully.<br />';
     } else {
     echo 'Error: ' . $uniinsert . "<br>" . $db->error . '<br />';
     }
      }
    
    // store Author University_ID value

    $result = $db->query("SELECT University_ID FROM University WHERE University_Name = '$authoruni'");
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $authoruniid = $row['University_ID'];
    
    
    //Enter Author and Article in Articles_Authored
    $authoredquery = $db->query("SELECT Author_ID, Article_ID FROM Articles_Authored WHERE Author_ID = '$authorid' AND Article_ID ='$articleid'");
    if($authoredquery->num_rows != 0) {
       echo '<a href=""> New Input </a><br />';
       echo 'Article Authored entry for Author ' . $number . ' - ' . $author . ' - already present<br />';
   
    } else {
    $articlesauthoredinsert = "INSERT INTO Articles_Authored (Article_ID, Author_ID, Name_Authored_As) VALUES ('$articleid','$authorid','$author')";
    
     if ($db->query($articlesauthoredinsert) === TRUE) {
     echo 'Article Authored - Author ' . $number . ' - created successfully <br />';
     } else {
     echo 'Error: ' . $articlesauthoredinsert . "<br>" . $db->error . '<br />';
     }
    }
    
    //Enter Author University instance in Author_University
    $authoruniinsert = "INSERT INTO Author_University (Article_ID, Author_ID, University_ID) VALUES ('$articleid','$authorid','$authoruniid')";
    
     if ($db->query($authoruniinsert) === TRUE) {
     echo 'University instance for Author ' . $number  . ' created successfully<br />';
     } else {
     echo 'Error: ' . $authoruniinsert . "<br>" . $db->error . '<br />';
     }
    }

    
    
    //check if article exist
    $articlequery = $db->query("SELECT Article_Title, ISSN FROM Articles WHERE Article_Title = '$article_name' AND ISSN = '$journal'");
    if($articlequery->num_rows != 0) {
      echo '<a href=""> New Input </a><br />';
      echo "<script type= 'text/javascript'>alert('Article Already Present');</script>";
  
    } else {

    //insert article if doesn't exist 
    $articleinsert = "INSERT INTO Articles (ISSN, Year_Published, Is_Security, Article_Title)
    VALUES ('$journal','$year','$security','$article_name')";

     if ($db->query($articleinsert) === TRUE) {
     echo 'New Article - ' . $article_name . ' - created successfully<br />';
     } else {
     echo 'Error: ' . $articleinsert . "<br>" . $db->error . '<br />';
     }
    // store Article_ID value
    
    $result = $db->query("SELECT Article_ID FROM Articles WHERE Article_Title = '$article_name' AND ISSN = '$journal'");
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $articleid = $row['Article_ID'];
    
    //insert author 1 info
    authorinfoinsert($author1, 1, $author1uni, $articleid, $article, $db);
    //check if Author 2 has input
    if (!empty($author2)){
     authorinfoinsert($author2, 2, $author2uni, $articleid, $article, $db);    
    }
    
    //check if Author 3 has input
    if (!empty($author3)){
     authorinfoinsert($author3, 3, $author3uni, $articleid, $article, $db);   
    }
    //check if Author 4 has input
    if (!empty($author4)){
     authorinfoinsert($author4, 4, $author4uni, $articleid, $article, $db);   
    }
    
    //check if Author 5 has input
    if (!empty($author5)){
     authorinfoinsert($author5, 5, $author5uni, $articleid, $article, $db);   
    }

    //check if Author 6 has input
    if (!empty($author6)){
     authorinfoinsert($author6, 6, $author6uni, $articleid, $article, $db);   
    } else{
     
     $db->close();
     
    }
   }
  }
 }
?>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: u want to add more button dynamically right??

Comment: i have posted my ans plz check and if have still doubt info me

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code to dynamically add dropdown with it's unique id, you can easily modify it according to your needs, i.e. change it to button...

**HTML:**

```
<a id="add">Add More</a>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var i = 1;
$("#add").click(function(){
                var appendFields = '<tr>';
                appendFields += '<td><select id="dropdown_'+i+'" name="dropdown_name[]"><option value="1">One</option></select></td>';
                appendFields += '<td><a style="color: red; cursor: pointer;" class="remCF">Remove</a></td>';
                appendFields += '</tr>';
                $("#table_id").append(appendFields);
                i++;
            });
            $("#table_id").on('click','.remCF',function(){
                $(this).parent().parent().remove();
            });

        });
```

Comment: It will need new id for each field that increases each time its clicked. This code will add a field but it won't solve problem.

Answer (score 0):

### Try this code and check diff ids on inspect element.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Dynamically add Textbox, Radio, Button in html Form using JavaScript</TITLE>
<SCRIPT language="javascript">
function add(type,c) {
//Create an input type dynamically.
var element = document.createElement("input");
var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value, 10);
value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
value++;
 document.getElementById('number').value = value; 

//Assign different attributes to the element.
element.setAttribute("type", type);
element.setAttribute("value", type);
element.setAttribute("name", type);
element.setAttribute("id", type+parseInt(value));


var foo = document.getElementById("fooBar");

//Append the element in page (in span).
foo.appendChild(element);

}
 </SCRIPT>
 </HEAD>
 <BODY>
 <FORM>
 <H2>Dynamically add element in form.</H2>
  Select the element and hit Add to add it in form.
 <BR/><input type="hidden" id="number" value="0"/>  
 <SELECT name="element">
<OPTION value="button">Button</OPTION>
<OPTION value="text">Textbox</OPTION>
<OPTION value="radio">Radio</OPTION>
 </SELECT>

 <INPUT type="button" value="Add" onclick="add(document.forms[0].element.value,1)"/>

 <span id="fooBar">&nbsp;</span>

 </FORM>
  </BODY>
 </HTML>
```